# How can I Access .exe file with python which is not made by python

Tags: python

I have two Software on my desktop that i want collect data from, one software contains (hashes gathered, this hashes is a file in the main program) and send it to the other software(pool).I am looking for the best  approach of grabbing the data from One software and feeding it to the other.

> > > these  are the libraries i have checked so far
> > > Pywinauto
> > > PEFILE
> > > uncompyle6

I don't  know what to do..

Comment: Welcome to SO! You probably don't want to hear this, but the short answer is: you can't. There are only 2 ways you can get data from inside someone else's `.exe`. 1. Run the program and catch its output in a file, then process the file. 2. If the program offers an API, use that.

Comment: Wow thanks...  can you please explain how to  do this ... i am a beginner!

Comment: Without the documentation, I can't possibly guess. But if it produces output there must be some way for you to specify where it should go. Typically a command-line program will offer  a runtime argument, for example `hashprogram.exe --output hashes\go\here.txt` or maybe you can redirect the output using `>` as in `hashprogram.exe > hashes\go\here.txt`. This is very vague and speculative but without documentation I can't be more specific. The moral, though, is that you can't get what you want by going behind that other programmer's back. You have to use whatever facilities the program provides.

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot! Now I understand better.. Assuming the output is gotten (the file), how can i pass it to the mining pool software,  can i also use the same method?

Comment: Again, only the documentation for the target program tell you that. And you may find yourself having to write a little reformatting program to adjust the source program's output to conform to what the target program expects as input. Python is a very good language for doing that, which is why you will sometimes hear it dismissed as a *glue language*. It is, but also many other things besides, in a way that other glue languages, for example Awk, can't match.

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks.  but the targeted programs both Hash and Pool was not really revealed, but the programs tend to function like every other app  in the market place, it generate hashes independently. i was ask to  develop app that could transfers into  mining software or url address. ... For my research for the past 2weeks you have really giving a handful  tips  and infor.  Thanks alot.

Comment: @BoarGules have been able to to use a subprocess module to the send the "stdout" to a file.txt... and use the "re" to search for the exact value i am looking. but i don't know how to call the mining pool software and pass the value to it, to automatically update the software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows exe can be automated with UIA or MSAA technology, so first use uispy or inspect tools to judge